# How to get the variable and its size after Declaration?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on clang Libtooling.

I wanted to get the information on array and its size ,when its again used.
I am facing difficulty on how to implement it.

This is my testfile

```
void test()
{
int array[5];
array[4]=8;
}
```

till now I was able to get the information like name of the array and its size at line number 3

for size I used this

```
if (const VarDecl *D = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::VarDecl> ("gotit")){

    auto t =  dyn_cast_or_null<ConstantArrayType>(D->getType().getTypePtr());           
    const llvm::APInt a = t->getSize();
    llvm::outs() << a;
    llvm::outs()<< "\n";
    llvm::outs()<< " array name is : " << D->getNameAsString();     
    }
```

But how can I get the information for the line number 4.

Like size is 4 and name is array. 
Kindly suggest me if any solution is available.

Comment: How about you save information about the array when you see the declaration, and when it's used you fetch the information from your own internal cache?

Answer (score -1):

The old style C-Arrays have exactly this drawback: The information how long the are is lost when you pass the array (as a pointer/address) around.

I personally recommend to not use them at all anymore.

Use the STL std::array if the size is known in advance and constant or std::vector if it has to grow dynamically. They alwyas know how big they are.

In particular, forget about char[], use std::string for all texts.